# Lookup table for new column in dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a dataframe, `dat`, where one of the columns, `dat$QC`, contains quality codes, as an integer. I want to add a new column, `QS`, containing the string describing the quality code for each row.

Here's what I have tried: I have stored the quality codes in a vector, `qcIDs`, and the strings in another vector, `qcStrings`. Then I loop over these and populate the new column in the dataframe accordingly. like this:

```
qcIDs <- c(1,2,3)
qcStrings <- c('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
for (ii in 1:length(qcIDs)) {
    dat$QS[dat$QC == qcIDs[ii]] <- qcStrings[ii]
}
```

I'm new to R and have read often there are better ways of solving problems than with `for` loops. Is there a more R-ish way of approaching this? Does the above look as clumsy as it feels to me (feels pretty clumsy)? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's most useful to end up with a factor in the data frame, simply create the factor using the given parameters.  Here's an example:

```
(dat <- data.frame(QC=rep(c(1,2,3), 2)) )
##   QC
## 1  1
## 2  2
## 3  3
## 4  1
## 5  2
## 6  3
```

Your parameters for the factor creation:

```
qcIDs <- c(1,2,3)
qcStrings <- c('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Use these to encode a factor in `dat`:

```
dat$QC <- factor(dat$QC, levels=qcIDs, labels=qcStrings)
dat
##    QC
## 1 foo
## 2 bar
## 3 baz
## 4 foo
## 5 bar
## 6 baz
```

I didn't time this, but it is going to be faster than any sort of merge.  There are no data comparisons going on here, just a reclass of the object.

Comment: it is not just better way than with `merge` - it's the right way. I am keeping my answer for reference and as an exhibit of why this answer is right.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! I knew that my way worked but it felt like it just wasn't the right way to go about it in this language. I wanted an answer that said "this is how we do things in R", so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` package

```
require("data.table")
lkp <- data.table(qcIDs = 1:3, qcStrings = c('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
dat <- data.table(QC = rep(1:3, 10e6))
setkey(dat,QC)
setkey(lkp,qcIDs)

result <- lkp[dat]

print(result)

#          qcIDs qcStrings
#        1:     1       foo
#        2:     1       foo
#        3:     1       foo
#        4:     1       foo
#        5:     1       foo
#       ---                
# 29999996:     3       baz
# 29999997:     3       baz
# 29999998:     3       baz
# 29999999:     3       baz
# 30000000:     3       baz


system.time(lkp[dat])
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.63    0.07    0.70
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using [merge](http://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html):

```
lookupQ = data.frame(qcID=c(1,2,3), QS=c('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
mergedDat = merge(dat, lookupQ, by.x="QC", by.y="qcID")
```